# Integração Spring MVC e catraca

Tags: spring-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para o restaurante universitário da minha universidade com Spring MVC.

> Preciso conectar o sistema com uma catraca da marca TopData, que controla o acesso dos clientes ao restaurante. Como nunca enfrentei tal problema, gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre qual caminho devo seguir!

Atualmente, estou pensando em criar uma aplicação Java Desktop para gerenciar a comunicação da catraca com o Sistema Web.

PS: a catraca tem saída de rede.

Comment: A fabricante da catraca certamente vai ter um manual descrevendo a API que você deve usar — e, caso você estivesse usando o modelo de conexão serial, provavelmente um _driver_ para se comunicar com o equipamento, também.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Modelo Catraca Box - com comunicação serial padrões RS232 e RS485.
- RS232: cabo com até 100m de comprimento RS485: cabo com até 1.500m de comprimento, permite a conexão de até 32 catracas ou Inners à mesma porta serial (necessário conversor RS232/RS485 conectado ao computador)
- Modelo Catraca Box Net - comunicação Ethernet 10/100 Mbps (TCP/IP)

qual modelo de catraca?
E ai vc saberá qual caminho terá que utilizar.

Edit : vi que falou que é o modelo net, é a mais fácil, o próprio fabricante tem um sdk.

de qualquer maneira esse link vai lhe ser interessante
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20679

e este também.
http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-a-api-rxtx-para-manipulacao-da-serial-parte-i/6722